# how can i fix this Javascript with to document write on multiple location.href.indexOf

Tags: javascript

how can i fix this JavaScript with to document write on multiple `location.href.indexOf`

```
if (location.href.indexOf( "/smispage""/tpfpage""/client_images_new""/client_images_list" ) > -1) {
    document.write( '<base target="_blank" />' );
}
```

It only seems to work on the **smispage** page regardless of how I lay out the list so:

```
"x","y" or "x";"y" or "x""y" or "x, y" or "x: y" or  "x,y" or "x;y"
```

Comment: You have syntax error in there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `indexOf` method simply doesn't have that functionality: it lets you search for a single substring, and that's it.

One alternative is to use [the `search` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search), which lets you specify a regular expression. In your case, that could look like:

```
if (location.href.search(/\/((smis|tpf)page|client_images_(new|list))/ ) > -1) {
    document.write( '<base target="_blank" />' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of the pages and loop to check if any of them matches..

```
var pages = ['/smispage','/tpfpage', '/client_images_new', '/client_images_list'];

for (var i = 0, len = pages.length; i < len; i++){
    if ( location.href.indexOf( pages[i] ) > -1 ){
        document.write( '<base target="_blank" />' );
        break;
    }
}
```